# Listing 'rake routes' for a mountable Rails 3.1 engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-routing, rails-engines

I'm working on a mountable engine for use with Rails 3.1, and I want to list the engine's routes.

I created the engine using:

```
$ rails plugin new rails_blog_engine --mountable
```

And edited the 'test/dummy/config/routes' file to read:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsBlogEngine::Engine => "/blog"
end
```

...and 'config/routes' to read:

```
RailsBlogEngine::Engine.routes.draw do
  resources :posts
end
```

I want to list the routes generated for ':posts', but it's not clear how I can do this. When I run 'rake app:routes', I get only the "/blog" route:

```
$ rake app:routes
rails_blog_engine    /blog    {:to=>RailsBlogEngine::Engine}
```

When I run 'rake routes', I get an error:

```
$ rake routes
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'routes'
```

How can I see the routes for ':posts'? Can I do this without rewriting the relevant rake tasks?

Comment: Now, in Rails 3.2.2, `rake app:routes` works fine. A simple `rake routes` does throw the same error, but that is expected.

Comment: Writing an engine today, I ran into this problem, and I just noticed I had the same problem 3 years ago! (ref my comment above) Some things never change, eh? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you copy code from the standard Rails 3.1.0 [rake routes](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7b619f1d7b3d261918592d4a9144d4a5d335d4b0/railties/lib/rails/tasks/routes.rake) task into your Rakefile, and change the top part to read:

```
task :routes => 'app:environment' do
  Rails.application.reload_routes!
  all_routes = RailsBlogEngine::Engine.routes.routes
```

...replacing RailsBlogEngine with the name of your engine, then you can get a rudimentary list of routes by running:

```
rake routes
```

Note that in Rails 3.1.1 and later, you'll need a [newer version of the rake routes](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/tasks/routes.rake) task.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me. Seems odd tho that this wouldn't be included out of the box.

Answer (score 24):

In case people are missing it in the comments, as of `Rails 3.2.2`, you can now use

```
$ rake app:routes
```

Answer (score 3):

For rails 3.x engine, `rake routes` does not work under engine's root (that's why it needs some hack by copying rake file). However `rake routes` works under test/dummy (or spec/dummy if using rspec). It will list all the pathes which belong to the engine in development and other engines mounted.

Answer (score 3):

For rails 3

```
 desc 'Print out all defined routes inside engine  match order, with names. Target specific controller with CONTROLLER=x.'
  task engine_routes: :environment do
    Rails.application.reload_routes!
    app = ENV['ENGINE'] || "Rails.application"
    all_routes = app.constantize.routes.routes
    require 'rails/application/route_inspector'
    inspector = Rails::Application::RouteInspector.new
    puts inspector.format(all_routes, ENV['CONTROLLER']).join "\n"
  end
```

Rails 4

```
 desc 'Print out all defined routes inside engine match order, with names. Target specific controller with CONTROLLER=x.'

  task engine_routes: :environment do
   app = ENV['ENGINE'] || "Rails.application"
   all_routes = app.constantize.routes.routes
   require 'action_dispatch/routing/inspector'
   inspector = ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesInspector.new(all_routes)
   puts inspector.format(ActionDispatch::Routing::ConsoleFormatter.new, ENV['CONTROLLER'])
  end
```

Then you can call like

```
 $rake engine_routes ENGINE="IssueTracker::Engine"
```

Comment: Thanks... from this I was able to figure out how to access the route url_helpers from the engine, for your example `"IssueTracker::Engine".constantize.routes.url_helpers` with which I could dynamically `send` to the path helper I needed.

Answer (score 1):

in Rails 5, I could get the routes of the engine using the following command:

```
bundle exec rake app:routes
```

Answer (score -1):

In rails 3.2X
If you are in you "host_app" and have mounted a engine you could probably list the routes by executing (should work out of the box):

```
bundle exec rake engine_name:routes
```