# All routing examples fail for a Rails 3.2 Engine with RSpec 2.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2, rspec-rails, rails-engines

I've created a Rails Engine in [the normal fashion](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#generating-an-engine), installed RSpec, and generated a scaffold for a model, but I can't get any routing specs to pass.

Here's one example:

```
describe Licensing::LicensesController do
  it 'routes to #index' do
    get('/licensing/licenses').should route_to('licensing/licenses#index')
  end
end
```

I'm running the examples in the dummy app like this:

```
$ cd spec/dummy
$ rake spec
/Users/brandan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby -S rspec ../routing/licensing/licenses_routing_spec.rb
F

Failures:

  1) Licensing::LicensesController routes to #index
     Failure/Error: get('/licensing/licenses').should route_to('licensing/licenses#index')
       No route matches "/licensing/licenses"
     # /Users/brandan/repos/licensing/spec/routing/licensing/licenses_routing_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.04345 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

The engine is mounted correctly in the dummy app:

```
# spec/dummy/config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Licensing::Engine => "/licensing"
end
```

And I can go into the dummy app and fire up the console and get that route just fine:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > app.get('/licensing/licenses')
  Licensing::License Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "licensing_licenses".* FROM "licensing_licenses" 
200
1.9.3p194 :002 > app.response.body
"<!DOCTYPE html>..."
```

There's some discrepancy between the dummy app and RSpec, and I can't figure out what it is. I've found several articles that claim to solve this problem, but none of them have helped, and several of them are specific to Rails 3.1:

- [Ryan Bigg's article on generating and testing engines](http://reinteractive.net/posts/2-start-your-engines)
- [Matthew Ratzloff's article on testing engine routes in Rails 3.1](http://www.matthewratzloff.com/blog/2011/09/21/testing-routes-with-rails-3-1-engines/)
- [Stefan Wienert's article on mountable engines](http://stefanwienert.net/blog/2012/02/15/rails-mountable-engine-useful-starting-point-with-rspec-factory-girl-and-friends/)
- [A mailing list message about testing routing helpers in Rails 3.2](http://www.mail-archive.com/rubyonrails-talk@googlegroups.com/msg106156.html)

Has anybody solved this problem in Rails 3.2/RSpec 2.10?

Comment: I'm assuming you're testing against a dummy app that integrates your engine. Are you sure that the engine is mounted in dummy app's routes? If yes, are you sure your spec is of `:type => :routing`?

Comment: @TanzeebKhalili I'm certain that the routes are correct because they work in the console and in the browser. I'm running the specs from within the dummy app. The files are under `spec/routing`, and explicitly specifying `:type => :routing` doesn't cause the examples to pass either. Any more ideas? :-/

Comment: How about the following changes: 1) Different described object: `describe "the routes" do ...` and 2) Different syntax: `{ :get => '/licensing/licenses' }.should be_routable`

Comment: @TanzeebKhalili Sorry, neither of those helped either. I found [a discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/pull/539) that seems to indicate this is a problem with Rails and not RSpec, but there's still no solution.

Comment: [Example Rspec Routes](https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/12/15/rails-rspec-examples-of-routing-specs/#more-1623)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update (2013-10-31)**

RSpec 2.14 now [fully supports engine routes](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-14/docs/routing-specs/engine-routes):

```
module MyEngine
  describe ExampleController do
    routes { MyEngine::Engine.routes }
  end
end
```

Add it to all routing specs:

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb
config.include Module.new {
  def self.included(base)
    base.routes { Reportr::Engine.routes }
  end 
}, type: :routing
```

---

The best solution I've been able to find so far is explicitly setting the route set that will be used during the tests:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, type: :controller) { @routes = Licensing::Engine.routes }
  config.before(:each, type: :routing)    { @routes = Licensing::Engine.routes }
end
```

Then I had to rewrite my routing examples to omit the namespace:

```
it 'routes to #index' do
  get('/licenses').should route_to('licensing/licenses#index')
end
```

This seems like a bit of a hack, but it does make sense. I'm not testing whether Rails is able to mount an engine at a particular path. I'm only testing that my engine has correctly set up its own routes. Still, I'd rather not have to overwrite an instance variable to make it happen.

Here are another couple of good threads on this topic:

- [How to test routes in a Rails 3.1 mountable engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691594/how-to-test-routes-in-a-rails-3-1-mountable-engine)
- [How do I write a Rails 3.1 engine controller test in rspec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200654/how-do-i-write-a-rails-3-1-engine-controller-test-in-rspec)

Comment: yes, and there is

    routes { Licensing::Engine.routes }

to replace it: you can add this to a spec, but I just have to find a solution to add this to __all__ controller-specs of an engine...

Comment: @mugwump I added an example showing how to include the routes for all routing specs at once in `spec_helper.rb`.

Comment: @Brandan thank you! works&helps to dry out my specs!

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to explicitly inform RSpec that you are using a namespaced Rails route. EG,

```
# :use_route => ENGINE_NAMESPACE
:use_route => 'licensing'
```

Additionally, why not simplify the writting of RSpec controller tests like this,

```
describe Licensing::LicensesController do
  it 'GET index' do
    get :index, use_route: 'licensing'
  end
end
```

Here's a link for RSpec controllers I did,
https://github.com/westonplatter/questionnaire_engine/tree/engine/spec/controllers

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question is specifically about routing tests — i.e., I want to explicitly test that `/licensing/licenses` routes to the correct controller and action, not just that I can `get :index` on a given controller. I think I may have found a solution, although it's not pretty.