# Rspec: adding before to all tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-engines

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691594/how-to-test-routes-in-a-rails-3-1-mountable-engine/7967503#7967503) stackoverflow q, adding the following line solves the same problem faced that is explained in the question:

```
before(:each) { @routes = MyEngine::Engine.routes }
```

The last part of the thread explains that I do not have to add that line in every controller file if I add the following:

```
#spec/spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # other code
  config.before(:each) { @routes = MyEngine::Engine.routes }
end
```

However, this last part doesn't seem to work. Any idea why?

Thanks!

**Update 1**
example error message:

```
11) Core::PostsController PUT update with valid params assigns the requested post as @post
     Failure/Error: put :update, {:id => post.to_param, :post => valid_attributes}, valid_session
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:id=>"1", :post=>{}, :controller=>"core/posts", :action=>"update"}
     # ./spec/controllers/core/posts_controller_spec.rb:115:in `block (4 levels) in <module:Core>'
```

Comment: Do you get any error message while running your tests?

Comment: I have updated the question with an example error message

Comment: You sure that maybe that route just really doesn't exist?

Comment: The test passes as soon as I add that before statement after the describe part within my test file ... which is why I find it really bizarre.