# Named routes in mounted rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mount, rails-engines, named-routing

I'm making a small rails engine which I mount like this:

```
mount BasicApp::Engine => "/app"
```

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431687/listing-rake-routes-for-a-mountable-rails-3-1-engine) I have verified that all the routes in the engine are as the should be:

However - when I (inside the engine) link to a named route (defined inside the engine) I get this error

```
undefined local variable or method `new_post_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000065e0c08>:0x000000065d71d0>
```

Running "rake route" clearly verifies that "new_post" should be a named path, so I have no idea why Rails (3.1.0) can't figure it out. Any help is welcome

my config/route.rb (for the engine) look like this

```
BasicApp::Engine.routes.draw do
  resources :posts, :path => '' do
                resources :post_comments
                resources :post_images
        end
end
```

I should add that it is and isolated engine. However paths like main_app.root_path works fine - while root_path does not

Comment: If you got here because you're having issues with the Blogit gem - you can ignore the solutions below (which do work for other apps) and go to your blogit.rb file and uncomment the line that says: config.inline_main_app_named_routes = true

Answer (score 65):

#### The right way

I believe the best solution is to call `new_post_path` on the Engine's routes proxy, which is available as a helper method. In your case, the helper method will default to `basic_app_engine`, so you can call `basic_app_engine.new_post_path` in your views or helpers.

If you want, you can set the name in one of two ways.

```
# in engine/lib/basic_app/engine.rb:
module BasicApp
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    engine_name 'basic'
  end
end
```

or

```
# in app/config/routes.rb:
mount BasicApp::Engine => '/app', :as => 'basic'
```

In either case, you could then call `basic.new_posts_path` in your views or helpers.

#### Another way

Another option is to not use a mounted engine and instead have the engine add the routes directly to the app. [Thoughtbot's HighVoltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) does this. I don't love this solution because it is likely to cause namespace conflicts when you add many engines, but it does work.

```
# in engine/config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts, :path => '' do
                resources :post_comments
                resources :post_images
  end
end

# in app/config/routes.rb:
# (no mention of the engine)
```

Comment: What if you want to access the main application's named routes from inside the engine?

Comment: @jphager2 would you call main_app?

Comment: Didn't know that helper existed. Very handy. Thanks!

Comment: It is well documented in [rails engine routes guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#routes) since 3.1

Answer (score 18):

On Rails 4 the `engine_name` directive did not work for me.
To access a named route defined in engine's routes from engine's own view or controller, I ended up using the verbose

```
BasicApp::Engine.routes.url_helpers.new_post_path
```

I recommend defining a simple helper method to make this more usable

```
# in /helpers/basic_app/application_helper.rb

module BasicApp::ApplicationHelper
  def basic_app_engine
    @@basic_app_engine_url_helpers ||= BasicApp::Engine.routes.url_helpers
  end
end
```

With this in place you can now use

```
basic_app_engine.new_post_path
```

In case you need to access your main application helper from the engine you can just use `main_app`:

```
main_app.root_path
```

Comment: AFAIK `BasicApp::Engine.routes.url_helpers` generates a new `Module` and defines all the path/url helper methods every time you invoke it. It can quickly become a performance and memory problem. So I'd recommend including it in the class where you want to use it.

Comment: @tmichel is right, memoization must be used to avoid Module generation on very call. Try (untested!) `return @@basic_app_engine_url_helpers ||= BasicApp::Engine.routes.url_helpers`

Comment: neither of the solutions in the "right way" above worked for me. Mounting the engine routes as '<helper_name>' just created what looks like a copy of main_app, or at least an object with the same methods. This way does what the others should, but I'm still curious why the others don't work.

Answer (score 4):

use the below in you app to access the engine routes

```
MyApp::Engine.routes.url_helpers.new_post_path
```

Comment: don't do this, it regenerates the url_helpers module on each call, it's better to memoize the result into a variable in your desired scope in a helper method. as @Epigene demonstrated