# Getting error while using RefineryCMS Blog route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, refinerycms

I instructed *config/routes.rb* to use Refinery Blog as a root directory:

```
root :to => "refinery/blog/posts#index"
mount Refinery::Core::Engine, :at => '/'
```

In a app/view/layouts/_header.html.slim I'm trying to use `blog_root` route. For example:

```
= link_to (image_tag "/logo.gif"), blog_root, class: "brand"
```

The route is listed when I issue `rake routes`:

```
blog_root        /blog(.:format)      refinery/blog/posts#index
```

But nothing shows up, the system gives an error:

```
undefined local variable or method `blog_root' for 
#<#<Class:0x00000005e62f80>:0x007fd7241d94c8>
```

Also, I tryed `blog_root_path`, but it didn't work either.

Anything I can do in this situation? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029192/named-routes-in-mounted-rails-engine) pair was helpful.

I looked inside *config/routes.rb* of main app, and in comments it was writted that '*We ask that you don't use the :as option here, as Refinery relies on it being the default of "refinery"*'.

So, the working route is `refinery.blog_root_path`.

Comment: yep, all your paths need to be prefixed with "refinery".