# rails scope root and multiple apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have a working rails app accessible directly from `http://0.0.0.0:3000/` . The app is also in staging and production in heroku.

Today, I want to start working on a new rails app in the same computer. How can I start working on the new unrelated app under a different path without messing up my staging/production urls ?

How can I have something like this locally and switch between the two apps

```
 http://0.0.0.0:3000/existingApp/
 http://0.0.0.0:3000/newapp/
```

I tried `scope "/existingApp" do` in my routes.rb for / and I suppose I should do that for the new app as well... but how do I specify this only for my local environment? I would like my heroku urls to stay unchanged (ie stay at the root).

Comment: Is there a reason you need both `rails server`s working at the same time?

Comment: Within your `routes.rb`, you could wrap the `newapp` routes in `if Rails.env.development?` and old routes in `else` block. But maybe you could elaborate on why you need this kind of behaviour.

Comment: @ptd do I need two rails servers if I want to work on two applications? They do not need to run at the same time

Comment: You do not. Just stop the one server and start the other in your new rails project. They will both work normally on port 3000.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend doing what you're doing, but if you're gonna do it anyway, you could try writing an engine and mounting it.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029192/named-routes-in-mounted-rails-engine) could help get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Almost any server would be able to be configured to listen to a port other than 3000.  Thin, for example, can be started as:

```
thin -R config.ru -a 127.0.0.1 -p 8080 start
```

And would then listen on port 8080.  Rails server can be started similarly using:

```
rails server -e production -p 4000
```

You may want to also consider starting your database using a port different than the standard one, but that is probably not necessary.